# Consensus on when markdown code formatting should be used

Tags: discussion, formatting

I've noticed that there is some missuse of `markdown code formatting` here. Before I go around editing it out, it would be good to come to a consensus on when it is appropriate.

In my opinion, the following is true:

##### Appropriate

- Code blocks (obviously), e.g.

  ```
  def id_func(x):
      if x.featuretype == 'gene':
          new_id = x.attributes['ID'][0]
      elif x.featuretype == 'CDS':
          new_id = '-'.join( [x.attributes['ID'][0], x.seqid, str(x.start), str(x.end)] )
      return new_id
  ```
- Error messages and other formatted text output, e.g.

  ```
  print("1" + '"' + str(fastaIdx) + '"' + '"' + str(mrna_id) + "'" + db.strand())
  AttributeError: 'FeatureDB' object has no attribute 'strand'
  ```
- Formatted data, e.g.

  ```
  Seq_18  Liftoff gene    653259  653653  .       +       .       ID=QZVMAR_2781_gene_1
  Seq_18  Liftoff CDS     653259  653334  .       +       .       ID=Seq_8_Seq_8_Manual.BlastoST7C_030513:00:54_1;Parent=QZVMAR_2781_gene_1
  Seq_18  Liftoff CDS     653370  653458  .       +       .       ID=Seq_8_Seq_8_Manual.BlastoST7C_030513:00:54_1;Parent=QZVMAR_2781_gene_1
  Seq_18  Liftoff CDS     653489  653543  .       +       .       ID=Seq_8_Seq_8_Manual.BlastoST7C_030513:00:54_1;Parent=QZVMAR_2781_gene_1
  Seq_18  Liftoff CDS     653577  653653  .       +       .       ID=Seq_8_Seq_8_Manual.BlastoST7C_030513:00:54_1;Parent=QZVMAR_2781_gene_1
  ```
- Referring to inline function names, e.g.

  > You should only use `printf` when....

##### Not appropriate

- When `emphasising` words in a sentence
- When referring to the name of a piece of software `pandas` or programming language `python`
- Anything else that isn't covered by the above points

##### Up for discussion

- When referring to filenames `test.fastq`

Does the comminity agree? Are there any additions or removals that people think are appropriate?

Comment: Can you please explain more about why you think it's a grey area for file names, but not appropriate for program names? They seem like similar classes of things to me.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary** A distinction between library and function/method appears to be at the heart of this proposal. I can't see this proposal working for *inline* text for **OO code** (such as Python) because it is not practical to separate the library from a method (equivalent of a function).

**Background** Specifically on a spectrum from Python to `pandas` and then to `printf`. `pandas` is a library imported into Python. It's popular possibly because it's faster (for Python). It uses a sort of type casting, which I assume speeds its interaction with the underlying C.

**Issues for *inline* text**

1. For *inline* text what's the difference between `printf` (which is very C, but also Perl) and `pandas`, neither are standalone languages? If there is a distinction, where is the line drawn, for example what about `math.h` (C), `numpy` or for example `pathlib` which are all 'libraries'? If libraries are excluded (of which `pandas` is one) what about the methods (OOP) that they are importing? For example, would `Path` in `pathlib` library be okay (thats a method), but the `pathlib` library itself be excluded from the proposal?
2. Is there a distinction between *functions* and *methods*, i.e. between a non-OOP language and an OOP? I assume `f strings` or `format` (Python's equivalent to `printf`) are fine, but these are methods rather than functions. If methods were excluded it would be a bit limiting to an OOP coder.
3. Furthermore, OOP uses libraries and method calls in the unit of code, i.e. **"** *library*.*method* **"**. For example, the `pandas` library calls methods within the code not on import, so in the code below (`df = pd.DataFrame()`) would literally read **pd.`DataFrame`** as *inline* text. This is because `DataFrame` is the method and `pd` is the abbreviation for the library its from, i.e. `pandas`. The proposal appears to permit the *method* to be greyed out in inline text but the library isn't.

---

I assume that the proposal for `pandas` i.e.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
```

Would not extend to

`import` pandas `as pd`

`df = pd.DataFrame()`

I hope thats right?